# Object.entries is working partially in REACT why?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, recharts

I'm not able to display only : `"Mona", "Paul","Bastian"`, I can display :
`"Mona", "Paul","Bastian","Average"` but I don't want to display "Average".
And display "Average", in my second bloc of `radars [{...}, { name: 'Average',dataKey: 'Average'}`. What is wrong please??

```
const { names, locations } = graphs ?? {}
function RadarNames() {
    const data = Object.entries(graphs.names[0]).map(([key, value]) => ({
        "name": key,
        "age": value,
    }))
    return creacteChart({
        data: data,
        polarAngleAxisOptions: { dataKey: 'name' },
        radars: [
            {
                name: 'name',
                dataKey: 'age',
            
            },
            {
                name: 'Average',
                dataKey: 'Average',
             
            },

        ],
    })
}
```

I tried to do :

```
const data = Object.entries(graphs.names[0]!=='Average'? graphs.names[0].map(([key, value]) => ({"name": key,"age": value})):'')
```

But it's not working...

My json from my api is :

```
{
    "names": [
        {
            "Mona": 63,
            "Paul": 29,
            "Bastian": 31,
            "Average": 75
          }
      
    ],

    "locations": [
        {
            "location": "Dublin",
            "country":"Irland"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you return your JSON correctly from your API so that there is no average in the names block?

Comment: i'm not able to do that, it's how I have this format ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter`:

```
const data = Object.entries(graphs.names[0])
                   .filter(([key]) => key != "Average")
                   .map(([name, age]) => ({name, age}));
```

An alternative, is to spread the object to extract the Average (and ignore it) and get the rest in a new object:

```
const {Average, ...rest} = graphs.names[0];
const data = Object.entries(rest)
                   .map(([name, age]) => ({name, age}));
```

Comment: `radars:[{...}, {  name: 'Average', dataKey: 'Average' }`, is there a way to plot this `Average` for each name :`"Mona", "Paul","Bastian"`, because for now I've anything plotted..., usually it works fine when I have the right format...

Comment: That seems to be a different question. I don't know the recharts API, but I suspect you cannot use `dataKey: 'Average'` unless you have such a key in your data. But your original question was about  excluding the `'Average'` key, which I think I've answered.

Comment: And display "Average", in my second bloc of radars [{...}, { name: 'Average',dataKey: 'Average'}. that was the second part of my question but I can open a new issue ?

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest that. Looking back, I think this question may have been too broad as its title was only focusing on the problem with `Object.entries` not filtering the data, while you seem to have another question that is really tied to what you expect the recharts library to do with the data -- and as I said -- I don't know this API, so I cannot help you there. Well, I could dive in its documentation, but I'm sure you can do that too.

Comment: I've just  opened a new [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72802672/formatting-json-with-objet-entries-with-react) if you can take a look at it please

Answer (score 0):

```
graphs = {
    "names": [
          {
            "Mona": 63,
            "Paul": 29,
            "Bastian": 31,
            "Average": 75
          }
      
    ],

    "locations": [
        {
            "location": "Dublin",
            "country":"Irland"
        }
    ]

    };

const { names, locations } = graphs ?? {}

function RadarNames() {
    const data = Object.entries(graphs.names[0]).filter(([key]) => key != "Average").map(([key, value]) => ({
        "name": key,
        "age": value,
    }))

    const dataAv = Object.entries(graphs.names[0]).filter(([key]) => key == "Average").map(([key, value]) => ({
        "Average": key,
        "average": value,
    }))

    return ({
        data: data, dataAv,
        polarAngleAxisOptions: { dataKey: 'name' },
        radars: [
            {
                name: 'name',
                dataKey: 'age',
            
            },
            {
                name: 'Average',
                dataKey: 'average',
             
            },

        ],
    })
}

console.log(RadarNames());
```

Comment: Is there something different in this answer compared to what was posted 25 minutes earlier? Can you add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: radars:[{...}, {  name: 'Average', dataKey: 'average' }, is there a way to plot this Average for each name :"Mona", "Paul","Bastian", because for now I've anything plotted..., usually it works fine when I have the right format...

Comment: he wanted to display Average in a second bloc not just to exclude it, so I added a new constant and change the filter

Comment: Not working but I have opened a new [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72802672/formatting-json-with-objet-entries-with-react)  using `Object.entries`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I reposted the entire code,  for me it worked, maybe he has a problem with his json api